# def on_start() not being called but regular function does

Tags: python, kivy

"on_start" is never being called when the program starts, but "filter" is.

I don't understand why "filter" is running and "on_start" is not.

Can anyone help me here?

```
    class Principal(Screen):

def on_start(self):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("data.db", 5)
    c = conn.cursor()
    lista = c.execute('''SELECT * FROM blackbelts''').fetchall()
    for e in lista:
        self.ids.lista.add_widget(ThreeLineListItem(text=e[1], secondary_text=e[2], tertiary_text=e[3]))
    return print(lista)

def filter(self, termo):
    if termo in self.ids.listaitem.text or termo in self.ids.listaitem.secondary_text:
        #self.on_start()
        print("termo encontrado")

    else:
        print("termo não encontrado")
```

Updated and full code as asked:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.app import Builder
import json
import sqlite3
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.uix.list import MDList, ThreeLineListItem


class Principal(Screen):

    def updatelist(self):

        conn = sqlite3.connect("data.db", 5)
        c = conn.cursor()
        lista = c.execute('''SELECT * FROM blackbelts''').fetchall()
        for e in lista:
            self.ids.lista.add_widget(ThreeLineListItem(text=e[1], secondary_text=e[2], tertiary_text=e[3]))
        return

    def filtrar(self, termo):

        if termo in self.ids.listaitem.text or termo in self.ids.listaitem.secondary_text:
            self.ids.lista.clear_widgets()
            self.updatelist()
            print("termo encontrado")

        else:
            print("termo não encontrado")

    def on_enter(self, *args):

        print("tela entrou")
        return


class Segunda(Screen):

    pass


class Terceira(Screen):

    def adicionar(self, nome, faixa, academia, time, datagraduacao):

        conn = sqlite3.connect("data.db",5)
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blackbelts (ID INTEGER, nome TEXT, apelido TEXT, academia TEXT, 
        time TEXT,datagraduacao TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(ID, nome) )''')
        conn.commit()
        params = nome, faixa, academia, time, datagraduacao
        c.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO blackbelts VALUES(NULL,?,?,?,?,?)''', params)
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        return True

class BlackBeltAPP(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        KV = Builder.load_file("blackbelt.kv")
        return KV

if __name__ == '__main__':
    BlackBeltAPP().run()
```

this is getting me a the **getAtrr** error as follows:

File "/Users/cassio/PycharmProjects/profjiu/main.py", line 17, in updatelist
     self.ids.lista.add_widget(ThreeLineListItem(text=e[1], secondary_text=e[2], tertiary_text=e[3]))
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 863, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.**getattr**
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**'

Comment: Looks like a part of the code is missing. Can you add where the class Principal is called?

Comment: The `Screen` class does not support an `on_start()` method.

Comment: So, even though I have moved on_start() to the App class and it has been called, list is not being updated.

Workaround I did: for some reason the "filter" function is being called on initialization (it takes data from an input field in the kv file and update the list to filter it). So I renamed the "on_start()" function under Primeira() and called it on the filter() func.

Now... could you help me understand why "filter" is being called? Are there any char being passed in the initialisation of the input widget, maybe?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a method to be called automatically when the `screen` enters, use `on_enter(self)`

Comment: it kind of worked. It is running to print a statement, but when I try to update the list, wither directly or by calling a function I get this error:

        AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'